# Spring Integration `RotatingServerAdvice` Polling

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-sftp

When `RotatingServerAdvice` is added as an advice to a `Poller`, as in

```
PollerSpec pollerSpec = Pollers.cron(cronExpression)
                                       .advice(rotatingServerAdvice(sftpConfig, proxyConfig))
                                       .maxMessagesPerPoll(3)
                                       .errorChannel("errorChannel");
```

will the poller rotate through each `RotationPolicy.KeyDirectory` at the scheduled time, or will it check one directory per poll? I've checked the examples in the Spring Integration Github repo and the reference documentation but I'm not able to get clarity on this. I'm guessing it should be the first, but I'd like to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, clarify why do you see a difference between scheduled time an poll? The poll really happens only when scheduler comes to the task to perform.

There is a `fair` option for you to consider. See docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-rotating-server-advice

Comment: Just to clarify; since you have  `maxMessagesPerPoll = 3`; the advice will be called up to 3 times per poll (the `MessageSource` is advised, so before/after each call to the `receive()`). If the current directory has 0, 1, or 2 files and `fair` is false; the rotation is on the next poll; with 3 or more, the rotation will happen on the next poll after the directory is empty. If `fair` is true and the current directory has 1 or more files, the rotation will occur after the first file is returned.

Comment: Thank you @ArtemBilan and @GaryRussell, this is helpful. I appreciate that both of you are so available to answer questions. I think in my case I will leave `fair` as `false`, and remove the `maxMessagesPerPoll` setting based on @GaryRussell's explanation.

Comment: Right. It depends from case to case, but Gary is correct: the `RotatingServerAdvice` is called for each message to poll from the source. So, it really may happen that your dirs are rotated during a single polling cycle - not waiting for the next schedule.

Comment: @ArtemBilan   Is there any way to rotate the local directory also based on the which remote directory is polled ?

Comment: Implement a `MessageSourceMutator` which would iterate over those local dirs when its `afterReceive()` is called. We also have an opened issue to support dynamic dir as an expression for the `FileReadingMessageSource`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/7971